# Can I push_back RectangleShapes into a 2d vector of a class that inherits RectangleShape?

Tags: c++

```
class tile :public RectangleShape
{
public:
int w;
int t1rgb1;
int t1rgb2;
int t1rgb3;
int t2rgb1;
int t2rgb2;
int t2rgb3;

void modify(int,int,int,int,int,int,int);
};
```

I have a tile class that inherits RectangleShape. I've made a 2d Vector of this class and want to push_back Rectangle shapes into it from a method of another class. I know my code won't work because I don't know where my RectangleShape will be push_back'ed into, x or y.

```
    board::create(int x, int y){
    cBoard = vector <vector <tile> >(x, vector< tile >(y, tile()));
    int counter = 0;
    RectangleShape t;

    for(int i = 0; i < y; i++){
        counter = 0;
        if(i % 2 == 1){
            counter = 1;
                }
    for(int ii = 0; ii < x; ii++){
        if(counter % 2 == 0){
            t.setFillColor(Color::Red);
            cBoard.push_back(t);
            cout << "red";
            counter++;
        }
        else if(counter % 2 == 1){
            t.setFillColor(Color::Green);
            cBoard.push_back(t);
            cout << "green";
            counter++;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't. Changing it to a 1D vector won't help either.

If you want to combine a container with inheritance, you almost certainly need the container to store some sort of pointer-like or reference-like thing, rather than storing the objects directly.

Depending on the situation, those might be `std::unique_ptr`, or `std::reference_wrapper`, or possibly just raw pointers in something like a [Boost `ptr_vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html). One way or another, however, if you're using inheritance, you just about need to deal with the objects via something pointer-like or something reference-like rather than working directly with objects themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this kind of thing is using dynamic_cast and store pointers, rather than values.  For example:

```
RectangleShape r1 = new RectangleShape();
RectangleShape r2 = new tile();

tile* t1 = dynamic_cast<tile>(r1);
tile* t2 = dynamic_cast<tile>(r2);
```

In the above code snippet, t1 will be nullptr, because r1 is not a tile object.  t2 will point to the correct tile object.  Storing the pointers in a vector should probably be done with unique_ptr to prevent memory management issues.

If this is not what you want to do, if you want to actually create a tile object out of a RectangleShape object, then you would need to give the tile class a constructor that takes a RectangleShape object (preferably explicit), or create a function that takes a RectangleShape object and returns a tile object.

Finally, make sure when you're doing this that RectangleShape is actually the kind of object you would want to derive another class from.  It must have a virtual destructor, and any overriden methods should also be virtual.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating more on what giving the tile class a constructor that takes a RectangleShape obj or creating a func that takes a RectangleShape and returns a tile obj looks like?